# How are rishis not able to control anger despite doing meditation?

Tags: shiva, rishi, indriyas

Lord Shiva does Dhyana almost all of the time. Then why can't he control his anger? There were some very famous Rishis known for their bad tempered. How also they unable to control their anger?

Comment: Being angry is not bad, being identified with the anger or not knowing who is in anger or who is not is the sign of bounded souls. Lord Shiva or Rishis who were angry knew who were angry & who were not & they were not identified themselves with their anger. But this case is not with you. When your mind is angry then you superimpose limitations on your own self and forgets the distinction between who is in anger & who is not which results into bondage. You identified yourself with the mind in the anger & forgets your real nature.

Comment: Try to understand this - "Attraction and repulsion, pleasure and pain, rising and setting, self-confidence and depression; all these states with which the universe is formed shine as mutually different but in reality they are not. **Whenever you perceive the specificity of some thing, at that very moment you should perceive the essence of your own consciousness as one with it… why not take delight in the fullness of that awareness**."

Comment: You would rather  not answer?

Comment: How are cricketers unable to score hundred every match despite practicing ? It depends on the amount of practice. Some rishis are able to control, some are not. They are able to control some time, but not all the time.

Comment: Because of Ahankaara.

Comment: In addition to the other answers/comment - Sometimes anger is needed to be expressed by Shiva/rishi to deliver the person from their wrongdoings. It is called shaapanugraha.

Answer (score 1):

These rishis were in process of self realization. Anger suppose to be the most hidden dosha which takes control over unknowingly. Only after the self realization it happens that person victors the "Shad Ripu". Till then it is a roller coaster ride when persons earns punya by Tap and meditation and keep losing them by falling prey to anger and other doshas.

Comment: The answer is too general - any specific scriptural or source material for this conclusion. agreed logically the answer is acceptable - but is it an answer or just a comment.